# Automatically Sharding a Java Map across multiple nodes

Tags: java, dictionary, sharding

I have a problem where I need to assemble a Map whose eventual size is in the GBs (going on past 64GB) and I cannot assume that a user of the program will have this kind of monster machine hanging around. A nice solution would be to distribute this map across a number of machines to make a far more modest memory footprint per instance.

Does anyone know of a library/suite of tools which can perform this sharding? I do not care about replication or transactions; just spreading this memory requirement around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you start with hazelcast:

http://www.hazelcast.com/

It is open-source, and in my opinion it is *very easy* to work with, so it is the best framework for rapid prototyping.

As far as I as know, it performs faster than the commercial alternatives, so I wouldn't worry about performance either.
*(I haven't formally benchmarked it myself)*

Comment: hey kevin, you are right, that's why I quickly added the parenthetic remark :)

Answer (score 3):

terracotta might be useful have a look here

http://www.terracotta.org/

its a clustered jvm will depend on how often you update the map i guess on how well it performs.

Comment: If you're building a commercial product, the open source licensing for Terracotta can be a pain mainly because of the attribution clause

Comment: Licensing is not a problem as the project is open-source; Terracotta seemed a bit OTT plus I'm more worried about how well Terracotta can shared the data. eHcache though looks like it might be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Must it be open source? If not, [Oracle Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/coherence/index.html) can do it.

Comment: Agreed, it's exactly (and more) what he's looking for... It may be a little overkill though.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to solve your problem by using a database instead, something like http://hsqldb.org/ may provide the functionality you need with the ability to write the data to disk rather than keeping the whole thing in memory.

I would definitely take a step back and ask yourself if a map is the right data structure for GBs of data.

Comment: HSQLDB is too slow unfortunately & the data is nicely ordered into key-value pairs. The issue comes from a need to have extremely fast lookup without being able to predict the lookup order. That's why hash based solutions would seem to be better than going for a RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

[Gigaspaces Datagrid](http://www.gigaspaces.com/datagrid) sounds like the kind of thing you are looking for. (Not free though)